# Python: Writing utf-8 to file

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

So I have read countless articles throughout the forums and tried a plethora of suggestions, but I still can't get my code to do what I want it to, which is:

- After grabbing text from a website using BeautifulSoup (WORKS)
- Write that text to output file (WORKS)
- Using the right encoding (DOES NOT WORK).

Printing the text to Stout works just fine, too. But neither redirecting that output to output.txt, nor writing it straight into that file from python seems to work? Why is that?

Here's what works:

```
    print '$'.join(result).encode('utf-8')
```

Sample output:

```
    Bärensteiner Str.
```

Whereas neither this:

```
    myscript.py > output.txt
```

nor this:

```
    with codecs.open('output.txt', 'a', 'utf-8') as outfile:
      outfile.write('$'.join(result))
```

nor this:

```
    with open('output.txt', 'a') as outfile:
      outfile.write('$'.join(result).encode('utf-8'))
```

will work. All three of the above produce an output.txt with the following content:

```
    BÃ¤rensteiner Str.
```

I am at a loss and have (quite obviously) no proper grasp of how this encoding and decoding works...anyhow: Does any one of you smart people have an idea how I can get my code to work properly?

Comment: How do you verify the content of output.txt? Possibly it is wrongly decoded when loading.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including the bit where you pull data with BS

Answer (score 0):

Flagrant [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case.

Your file **is** `UTF-8` but it's displayed in another encoding, e.g. like

```
==> python -c print('Bären'.encode('utf-8').decode('Latin1')=='BÃ¤ren')
True

==> python -c print('Bären'=='BÃ¤ren'.encode('Latin1').decode('utf-8'))
True

==>
```

By [Character Encoding Errors Analyzer](http://string-functions.com/encodingerror.aspx):

> Expected result **Bären**
>
> Actual result **BÃ¤ren**
>
> <kbd>Analyze!</kbd>
>
> **Displaying 6 results**
>
> - utf-8 (65001, Unicode (UTF-8)) -> Windows-1252 (1252, Western European (Windows))
> - utf-8 (65001, Unicode (UTF-8)) -> windows-1254 (1254, Turkish (Windows))
> - utf-8 (65001, Unicode (UTF-8)) -> iso-8859-1 (28591, Western European (ISO))
> - utf-8 (65001, Unicode (UTF-8)) -> iso-8859-4 (28594, Baltic (ISO))
> - utf-8 (65001, Unicode (UTF-8)) -> iso-8859-9 (28599, Turkish (ISO))
> - utf-8 (65001, Unicode (UTF-8)) -> utf-7 (65000, Unicode (UTF-7))